# Ruby Program is not printing on screen

Tags: ruby

Good day everyone. I am writing a simple ruby code but it doesn't print on the screen I am using ruby 2.2.2 and my IDE is Rubymine 7.Thanks in advance.Here is the code;

```
class Animal    
  attr_accessor :name, :colour   
  def initialize(name,colour)   
    @name = name    
    @colour = colour   
  end   
  def to_s   
    "Name#{@name} Colour #{@colour}"   
  end   
end   
class Cheetah < Animal    
  attr_reader :speed   
  def initialize(name,colour,speed)   
    @speed = speed   
    super (name,colour)   
  end   
  def to_s   
     return super + "Speed#{@speed}kph"   
  end   
end   
class Zoo < Animal    
  def initialize   
    @animals = []    
  end    
  def add_animals(animal)    
    @animals << animal    
  end    
  def my_animals    
      cage = ""   
    @animal.each do|call|   
      cage += call.to_s   
    end   
  end    
end    
5.times do|count|    
  Zoo.add_animals(MyAnimal.new("Cheetah#{count}","yello and black spots"))   
end    
puts "#{Zoo.my_animals}"    
My_cheetah = Cheetah.new("Cheetah","yello and black spots",180)    
puts "#{My_cheetah.to_s}"
```

Comment: In the definition of `Zoo.my_animals` you're referencing `@animal` (i.e. not pluralized), also in that same method, you're building up a string (`cage`), but you never return it (the return value of a call to `.each` is nil).

Comment: The return value of `each` is `self`, as specified in the documentation of `each`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Animal    
  attr_accessor :name, :colour   
  def initialize(name,colour)   
    @name = name    
    @colour = colour   
  end  

  def to_s   
    "Name#{@name} Colour #{@colour}"   
  end   
end

class Cheetah < Animal    
  attr_reader :speed   

  def initialize(name,colour,speed)   
    @speed = speed   
    super(name,colour)   
  end   

  def to_s   
     return super + "Speed#{@speed}kph"   
  end   
end

class Zoo < Animal   
  def initialize   
    @animals = []    
  end    

  def add_animal(animal)    
    @animals << animal    
  end

  def my_animals    
    cage = ""   
    @animals.each do |call|   
      cage += call.to_s   
    end
    cage
  end    
end 

zoo = Zoo.new 
5.times do|count|    
  zoo.add_animal(Animal.new("Cheetah#{count}","yello and black spots"))   
end
puts "#{zoo.my_animals}"    

my_cheetah = Cheetah.new("Cheetah","yello and black spots",180)    
puts "#{my_cheetah.to_s}"
```

Comment: Rather than a code dump, indicate what needs to be changed, and *why*.

Comment: @DaveNewton That is absolutely right. In particular case the main need is to do some research by yourself rather than post such code on SO.

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko hey Maxim thanx plus everyone for the reply, I copied and pasted your code but unfortunately it also didn't print on screen.

Comment: @AllanBast It means you did not copy-paste correctly or did not run program correctly.